# Why do I get error "Error compiling for board Arduino Uno" with my mpu6050 video stabilization code?

Tags: arduino-uno, library, mpu6050, calibration

This is the code I'm working with. I'm using it for video stabilization system. It was working fine but for some reason now it gives me this error? Is it because I deleted the library and installed again? Please help. I'm new to arduino. Hopefully I formatted this correctly.

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h"
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
#include "Wire.h"
#endif

MPU6050 mpu;
Servo myServo;   // define servo
int servoPin=9;
float PWM = 0;
float Yaw = 0;

#define OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL
#define INTERRUPT_PIN 2
#define LED_PIN 13

bool blinkState = false;


// MPU control/status vars
bool dmpReady=false;    // set true if DMP init was successful
uint8_t mpuIntStatus;   // holds actual interrupt status byte from MPU
uint8_t devStatus;      // return status after each device operation (0 = success, !0 = error)
uint16_t packetSize;    // expected DMP packet size (default is 42 bytes)
uint16_t fifoCount;     // count of all bytes currently in FIFO
uint8_t fifoBuffer[64]; // FIFO storage buffer

// orientation/motion vars
Quaternion q;           // [w, x, y, z]         quaternion container
VectorInt16 aa;         // [x, y, z]            accel sensor measurements
VectorInt16 aaReal;     // [x, y, z]            gravity-free accel sensor measurements
VectorInt16 aaWorld;    // [x, y, z]            world-frame accel sensor measurements
VectorFloat gravity;    // [x, y, z]            gravity vector
float euler[3];         // [psi, theta, phi]    Euler angle container
float ypr[3];           // [yaw, pitch, roll]   yaw/pitch/roll container and gravity vector
//packet structure for InvenSense teapot demo


volatile bool mpuInterrupt=false;
void dmpDataReady(){
  mpuInterrupt=true;
}
// ================================================================
// ===                      INITIAL SETUP                       ===
// ================================================================
void setup()
{
  // join I2C bus (I2Cdev library doesn't do this automatically)
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000);
  
#elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE
  Fastwire::setup(400, true);
  
#endif

  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);      // wait for Leonardo enumeration, others continue immediately

  // initialize device
  Serial.println(F("Initializing I2C devices..."));
  pinMode(INTERRUPT_PIN, INPUT);
  // testing connection...
  Serial.println(F("Testing device connections..."));
  Serial.println(mpu.testConnection() ? F("MPU6050 connection successful") : F("MPU6050 connection failed"));
  // load and configure the DMP
  Serial.println(F("Initializing DMP"));
  devStatus = mpu.dmpInitialize();


  // INPUT CALIBRATED OFFSETS HERE; SPECIFIC FOR EACH UNIT AND EACH MOUNTING CONFIGURATION!!!!
  //fix offsets #s when we use mount
  mpu.setXGyroOffset(0);
  mpu.setYGyroOffset(0);
  mpu.setZGyroOffset(0);
  //mpu.setXAccelOffset(-651); //unneccesary
  //mpu.setYAccelOffset(670);  //also unneccesary
  mpu.setZAccelOffset(17);

  // make sure it worked (returns 0 if so)
  if (devStatus == 0){
    // Calibration Time: generate offsets and calibrate our MPU6050
     // mpu.CalibrateAccel(6);
     // mpu.CalibrateGyro(6);
     // mpu.PrintActiveOffsets();
    // turn on the DMP, now that it's ready
       Serial.println(F("Enabling DMP..."));
        mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);

    // enable Arduino interrupt detection
    Serial.print(F("Enabling interrupt detection (Arduino external interrupt 0)"));
    Serial.print(digitalPinToInterrupt(INTERRUPT_PIN));
    Serial.println(F(")..."));
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(INTERRUPT_PIN), dmpDataReady, RISING);
  
    mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();
    Serial.println(F("DMP ready! Waiting for first interrupt..."));
        dmpReady = true;
    // get expected DMP packet size for later comparison
    packetSize = mpu.dmpGetFIFOPacketSize();
  }else
  {
    // ERROR!
    // 1 = initial memory load failed, 2 = DMP configuration updates failed (if it's going to break, usually the code will be 1)
    Serial.print(F("DMP Initialization failed code = "));
    Serial.println(devStatus);
    Serial.println(F(")"));
  }

  // configure LED for output
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  myServo.attach(servoPin);
  PWM=0;
} 

//main program loop

void loop()
{
  // if programming failed, don't try to do anything
    if (!dmpReady) return;
    // wait for MPU interrupt or extra packet(s) available
    while (!mpuInterrupt && fifoCount < packetSize) {
        if (mpuInterrupt && fifoCount < packetSize) {
          // try to get out of the infinite loop
          fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
        }
        // other program behavior stuff here
    }


  //reset inerrupt flag Get INT_STATUS byte
  mpuInterrupt=false; 
  mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();

  // get current FIFO count
  fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

  // check for overflow (this should never happen unless our code is too inefficient)
  if (fifoCount<packetSize){
  
    // reset so we can continue cleanly
  }else if ((mpuIntStatus & _BV(MPU6050_INTERRUPT_FIFO_OFLOW_BIT)) || fifoCount >= 1024) {
    
    mpu.resetFIFO();
    Serial.println(F("FIFO overflow!"));
  
  }else if (mpuIntStatus & _BV (MPU6050_INTERRUPT_DMP_INT_BIT)){

   while (fifoCount>=packetSize)
  {
    // check for correct available data length
    //if (fifoCount < packetSize)
    //return; //  fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

    // read a packet from FIFO
    mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);

    // track FIFO count here in case there is > 1 packet available
    fifoCount -= packetSize;
   }
     #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_QUATERNION 
     //display quaternion values in easty matrix form: w x y x
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
            Serial.print("quat\t");
            Serial.print(q.w);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(q.x);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(q.y);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(q.z);

    #endif
    #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER
            // display Euler angles in degrees
            mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetEuler(euler, &q);
            Serial.print("euler\t");
            Serial.print(euler[0] * 180/M_PI);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(euler[1] * 180/M_PI);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.println(euler[2] * 180/M_PI);
        #endif
        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL
            // display Euler angles in degrees
            mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
            mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity);
            Yaw = ypr[0]*180/M_PI;
            Serial.print("ypr\t");
            Serial.print(ypr[0] * 180/M_PI);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(ypr[1] * 180/M_PI);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.println(ypr[2] * 180/M_PI);
        #endif
        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL
            // display real acceleration, adjusted to remove gravity
            mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
            mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);
            Serial.print("areal\t");
            Serial.print(aaReal.x);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(aaReal.y);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.println(aaReal.z);
        #endif
        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_WORLDACCEL
            mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
            mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
            mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);
            mpu.dmpGetLinearAccelInWorld(&aaWorld, &aaReal, &q);
            Serial.print("aworld\t");
            Serial.print(aaWorld.x);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(aaWorld.y);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.println(aaWorld.z);
        #endif 

    // blink LED to indicate activity
    blinkState = !blinkState;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, blinkState);
  }
  PWM= map(Yaw, -180, 180, 1860, 1140);
  myServo.write(PWM);
  Serial.println(PWM);
  Serial.println(Yaw);
}
```

If the error code is needed please let me know. It's too long to attach in the body

Comment: Only the first one perhaps two errors in compiler output are normally useful.  The ones that follow are often the result of the first error or the compiler's attempt to recover from it and sometimes end up being more misleading than helpful.  It's probably enough to paste just the top of the output.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I had multiples of some libraries. Don't know how that happened. But I uninstalled all the libraries, and manually installed the ones I needed. It works now.